# Pattern Program in C

Tags: c

I wish to print a pattern in C language like this:

```
2
2  3
3  4  5
4  5  6  7
5  6  7  8  9
```

Currently I have this:

```
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {   
        for(j=1;j<=5;j++)
        {   
            if(i>=j)
            {
                printf(" %d ",j+i-1);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And output is:

```
 1 
 2  3 
 3  4  5 
 4  5  6  7 
 5  6  7  8  9
```

How do I make it to start with `2`, then `2 3` and so on?? Please help.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Given that the `2` on the first line doesn't fit with the rest of the pattern, you need to handle it separately. I would just `printf( "2\n" );` and then begin the pattern at `i=2`.

Comment: The `j` loop can be simplified with `for(j=1;j<=i;j++)` and the subsequent comparison with `i` can be removed. BTW I usually try to run my loops from `0`, as in `for(i=0;i<5;i++)`.

Comment: thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe would you like something like...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int someBase = 2;
    int someLimit = 5;
    printf("%d\n", someBase);
    for(int i = 1; i < someLimit; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
            printf("%d ", i + j + someBase - 1);

        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much KemyLand!!!! as mentioned above, I am really really sorry for not responding to your answer...:-(

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    int i = 2;
    int shift = 0;
    printf("2\n");
    for(int len = 2; len < 6; len++){
        for(int j = i; j < i + len; j++){
            printf("%d\t", j+shift);  
        }
        printf("\n");
        shift++;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much ClsForCookies!!!!
and I am really really sorry for not responding to your answer...:-(